# Facebook app v2.3 review permission

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I want to submit a Facebook App v2.3 review for permission.

But the problem is that , I want to know that if I have Two different server (with two different domains) of the my software or program

1. Test Server
2. Live Server

I have tested, implemented and integrated facebook with extended permissions like manage_pages, publish_actions etc  in Test Server.

If the facebook app submitted for review got approved.

If I want to use the same FAcebook's app ID and Secrete Key in my  Live Server, Will it work or i have to create a new app and submit for live server ?

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the URLs and the App Domain in your App Settings and it should be fine. You definitely don´t have to create a new App for the Live Server, you would have to do the review again for that.